# Powershell pipe is not working with variable in PHP Exec

Tags: php, powershell, exec

I am getting result if i use below in php exec

```
exec("powershell get-aduser '$user' -properties * -server '$domain.company.com'", $output, $return_code);
```

But not with pipe. For example this doesnt work.

```
exec("powershell get-aduser '$user' -properties * -server '$domain.company.com'|select cn", $output, $return_code);
```

If i hardcode user and domain, it works. for example this works.

```
exec('powershell "get-aduser xyz -properties * -server abc.company.com | select  cn"', $output, $return_code);
```

I need to use variable for user and domain. currently it doesn't work for me with pipe. Can anyone help me on this.

Finally this worked for me. Thank you nogad. I have to use multiple domains based on the users input. so i didn't add company.com to $domain variable.

```
$cmd='powershell "get-aduser '.$user.' -properties * -server '.$domain.'.company.com | select -expand cn"';
exec($cmd, $output, $return_code);
```

Comment: the quotes in your working hard coded version and the 'dynamic' version are quite diffirent

Comment: yes. Because When i used variable within single quote, double quotes again issues came. so i had to change it.

Comment: whats the working valid syntax for the command?

Comment: First and third are working and valid. But i need the second one to work. Because i will need to use the pipe with variable

Comment: try: `$cmd='powershell "get-aduser '.$user.' -properties * -server '.$company.' | select  cn"';

exec($cmd, $output, $return_code);`

Comment: I tried as  $cmd='powershell "get-aduser '.$user.' -properties * -server '.$domain.company.com' | select cn"';   it throws an error "unexpected '' | select cn"'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) "

Comment: update the question with the new *exact* code

Comment: put "company.com" in the domain string

Comment: https://ideone.com/sgIweT

Comment: Thank you nogad. Your Solution fixed the issue.